# Print a string as many times as the argument passed to the script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to print a string like "hello world" as many times as the argument passed to the script.

```
import os
import sys
usernum = int(sys.argv[1])
```

for example: `python script.py 2`

```
"hello world"

"hello world"
```

Comment: You have the number in `usernum`, you should check out [loops](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code sample:

```
import os
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("ERROR")
    sys.exit(1)

usernum = int(sys.argv[1])

for i in range(0,usernum):
    print("hello world")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way.

```
import os
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("ERROR")
    sys.exit(1)

usernum = int(sys.argv[1])

print "Hello world\n" * usernum
```